# Using Font Awesome in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to use Font Awesome with Vue 3.

I have it in my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
"@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-3",
}
```

Imported FontAwesome in `main.js`

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faPhone } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faAddressBook";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";

library.add(faPhone);

/* eslint-disable */
createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
    .component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
  .mount("#app")
```

And this inside component in `<template>`

```
 <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'faPhone']" />
```

But when I use it in component nothing is happening... In element is doent's render anything it only shows HTML comment
 `<!---->`
How can I fix this problem and start using FontAwesome in any Component?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

These steps got it working for me:

1. Install `latest-3` ([`3.0.1`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome/v/3.0.1)) of `vue-fontawesome`, which is compatible with Vue 3, and the icon dependencies:

   ```
   npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@latest-3
   npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
   npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
   ```
2. In `main.js`, select the icons from `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` to load:

   ```js
   import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
   import { faPhone } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

   library.add(faPhone);
   ```
3. Globally register the `font-awesome-icon` component:

   ```js
   import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";

   createApp(App)
     .component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
     .mount("#app");
   ```
4. In `src/App.vue`, use the component like this (note the icon name is `phone`, not `faPhone`):

   ```html
   <!-- explicit style -->
   <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'phone']" />

   <!-- implicit style (fas is assumed) -->
   <font-awesome-icon icon="phone" />
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-font-awesome?file=src%2Fmain.js)

Comment: Okay so problem was basically only that I wrote `['fas', 'faPhone']` instead of `['fas', 'phone']`

Comment: @tony19 while this solution has worked for most of the icons, it didn't work with [map-marker-exclamation](https://fontawesome.com/icons/map-marker-exclamation?s=solid&f=classic), is there anything that I should add?

Answer (score 32):

Tony19 is correct but if you want to avoid cluttering your main.ts(js) file, you can do something like this:

What you can do is create a separate file:

`fontawesome-icons.ts`

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faPhone, faUser, faFlag } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

library.add(faPhone, faUser, faFlag);

export default FontAwesomeIcon;
```

Then in your `main.ts`:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import "@/assets/css/main.scss";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import FontAwesomeIcon from "@/utilities/fontawesome";

createApp(App)
    .component("FontAwesomeIcon", FontAwesomeIcon)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 14):

Install

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

On your main.ts

```
import { library, dom } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
library.add(fas, far, fab)
dom.watch();

createApp(App)
    .component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
    .mount('#app')
```

To use on .vue files

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
<i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to display the icon without using the FontAwesome component because I have to pass it to a non-Vue library. This worked like a charm! It's the `dom.watch()` that makes the difference.

Comment: This option is the only one that worked for me on Vue 3. Nice solution to not have to import icons individually.

Answer (score 5):

for ease but compromising on **bundle size** and **speed**. you can **import all icons** at once

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

//Add all icons to the library so you can use it in your page
library.add(fas, far, fab)
```

source [official fontawesome docs](https://fontawesome.com/docs/apis/javascript/import-icons)

Answer (score 1):

**Install via command line**

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@latest-3
```

**In your main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(fas)

createApp(App)
  .component('fa', FontAwesomeIcon)
  .mount('#app')
```