# Where is library of all available icons for my vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I added font awesome in inertiajs/vue3 app
as I read here :
[Using Font Awesome in Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389974/using-font-awesome-in-vue-3)

So I have package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-5",
```

and icons are rendered ok with syntax like :

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'phone']" />
```

But where is library of all available icons for my version?
I tried to show dollar-sign/dollar and failed...

Thanks !

Comment: Did you import the dollar-sign icon to your app?

Comment: Have I to import any icon ? In which way ?

Comment: As you can see in the link you provided, they import a specific icon and add it to the library in either a specific file or the main js.

Comment: Could you please give link of all available icons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to add icons or icon bundles in your main.js or in your ts file depending on how you've set it up.

```js
import { faPhone } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faAddressBook";

library.add(faPhone);
```

Make sure you add the import of the icons and then also add the icon to the library. Below you can see entire bunldes of icons being added at once.

```js
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
```

To see a list of [all icons](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2).