# Why font awesome is not working with vue js?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I'm using Laravel and Vue js for my project. I want to use font awesome free icons in my project as of now. I followed these steps :

Here is how I installed font awesome within my project

## Step 1

```
    npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
```

## Step 2

```
    npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
    npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
    npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

## Step 3 - for Vue 3. x

```
    npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@latest-3
```

## Finally I tried it

```
    <template>
    <span class="w-8 h-8 bg-gray-400"><font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-house" /></span>
    </template>
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389974/using-font-awesome-in-vue-3

Comment: @RizaKhan I've tried that already that didn't work for me.

Comment: Have you registered the font-awesome-icon component globally?