# How to change the vuetify 3 font?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify 3 seems to default to the Roboto font. I want to change the font to Poppins, but there isn't clear documentation on how to do that.

I tried to change the font-family in app.vue styles by changing it in .v-application, but the font seems to still be roboto.

I also tried to create a .scss file in my scss folder and import it in main.js, that didn't seem to do it either.

Answer (score 0):

It's not defined in Vue documentation, because it's not Vue specific.

To change font application wide, define it in main.css file, what should be placed in assets directory.

Following posts might help with any follow-up questions.
[Using Font Awesome in Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389974/using-font-awesome-in-vue-3)

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the font in a CSS file, then import this CSS file into your main file (main.js).

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

html, body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#app {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

You need to verify if there is any reference to the Roboto font in your app and remove it.